# How to get a C# Image over to Monotouch

Tags: image, xamarin.ios, uiimage

I am connecting from monotouch through wcf to my windows c# host and wish to stream an image back to monotouch so I can display this.

My image is held in an System.Drawing.Image object which is not available in monotouch (it uses UIImage).

I was hoping to convert the Image on the host to a string like so:

```
        Image im = Image.FromFile(path);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        im.Save(ms, im.RawFormat);
        byte[] array = ms.ToArray();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(array);
```

And then using the opposite within MonoTouch to get my Image back again:

```
        byte[] array = Convert.FromBase64String(imageString);
        Image image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(array));
        return image;
```

This works fine in a 'pure' .net environment but monotouch doesn't recognise the Image object so it fails on that end.
How can I convert the byte[] back into a UIImage?

I tried things like this:

```
  UIImage img = (UIImage)UIImage.FromObject(bytes);
```

to no avail...

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of passing `im.RawFormat`, try using one of:

- `ImageFormat.Bmp`
- `ImageFormat.Png`

Depending on which format your images usually are.  These are in `System.Drawing.Imaging`, [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat.aspx).

This might cause trouble for other client applications, I would recommend having the client send something to determine what format the server returns.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question the technique works well in a .net environment. I am looking for help with how to do this in Monotouch - not just a list of different image formats. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Marcel I think you misunderstood Jonathan suggestion. The RAW format is not understood by `UIImage` but both the **PNG** and **JPEG** format are. Also both format are compressed - which means less data to transmit **and** less memory required (base64, array) to process. Both being great advantages for a mobile device.

Comment: @poupou - I see what you guys mean now - unfortunately I am away from my mac so can only check later.  Thanks for the explanation, I will let you know how it goes.  Thanks

Comment: @Marcel - I''m facing the same problem than yours. Do you find any solution ?